# iPad UISPlitViewController question

Tags: iphone, ipad

It is mentioned in the Apple's documentation that if we use UISPlitViewController in our app, then that should be the root view controller.

In our iPone app we are showing splash screen for some seconds till the loading of the app finishes. Once it is loaded the home screen needs to be displayed in a SplitViewController. If we use SplitViewController as the root view. How will we show the splash screen which is displayed in a single view where as SplitVieController displays two ViewControllers. Please explain me the how this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

In your application delegate's `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, add the splash screen as a subview of the main `UIWindow`.

Comment: oh, ok, What if I need to add a ProgressBar and it's delegate. Can we add it as a subview of splash image view

Comment: Can any one please add your comment on this

Comment: The splash screen can be any kind of view, even one you create. So yes, you can add subviews to it. But read @jamone's comment.

Answer (score 0):

OS 3.2 is still under beta NDA. You should ask on apple's developer forums.

Apple's HIG for iPhone OS has this to say about splash screens

> Display a launch image that closely resembles the first screen of the application. This decreases the perceived launch time of your application. For more information, see “Launch Images.”
>   Avoid displaying an About window, a splash screen, or providing any other type of startup experience that prevents people from using your application immediately.

Yes I know Apple has approved apps with splash screens but that doesn't mean you should too. Perhaps show your main screen with blank data and put a slight transparent overlay and a progress par to indicate loading (if you have intensive loading).